# How to have cloudfront distribution listen on custom port for HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, file-server

I have setup a Cloudfront distribution on AWS with custom domain name to fetch firmware update file from S3. However, the existing devices that we have with customers make an HTTPS request to that same custom domain name on port 4433 instead of the regular HTTPS port 443 to fetch the update file.

Is there some way to have the cloudfront distribution listen to HTTPS traffic on port 4433 as well or some other method to forward requests on port 4433 to 443 for a particular domain name ?

Some solution other than CDN may also work as long it can help us achieve high availability and is optimized to serve/download files from. Right now we host HTTPS servers on EC2 instances which remain largely idle when a file is not being downloaded.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: What other method would you suggest will be best suited to download a file from S3 over HTTPS port 4433(custom port) ?

Comment: FIx the clients to use the correct HTTPS port, or find a CDN that supports custom ports.

Comment: @ceejayoz Do you know of any CDNs that would support custom HTTPS ports ?